# Can a masked interrupt be received after the mask canceled?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt

If an interrupt is masked by "cli" instruction, can the same interrupt (not interrupts of the same source)be received by the cpu after a "sti" instruction?

Comment: Are you asking if masked interrupts are _queued_ after `cli` and handled after `sti`?

Answer (score 4):

In almost all reasonable interrupt applications, masking out an interrupt does just that; unmasking it will cause the CPU to accept any pending interrupt requests.

If that weren't the case, the very use of the interrupt mask would cause some interrupts to get lost due to narrow timing splinters (the software disables the mask at essentially the same time a new request appears; you don't want different behaviour just because one of these events occurred a femtosecond before the other).

If, after having masked out a class of interrupts ("all" or "level7" or whatever your hardware supports), you want a specific interrupt source to go away, your program should take explicit action while the interrupts are masked to tell the hardware to ignore/acknowledge that interrupt.

If we invert this idea, you can get some pretty slick OS/interrupt architectures.   Sometimes it is useful to process extremely high priority interrupts, but one wants to keep overhead at level low.  So a cheap trick often used when possible, is for the high-priority interrupt routine to do just a tiny bit of work and then punt the rest of the work to a lower priority level by *causing* an interrupt at that level.  Some hardware makes this possible.  This is especially handy if an interrupt routine at whatever level has accomplished work that should cause task rescheduling; it simply signals a low prority level interrupt whose service routine happens to be the scheduler.

Comment: Are masked interrupts queued after cli and handled after sti?

Comment: Typically an interrupt signal is held high by an interrupting device (by a latch in interrupting device) until it is serviced; you can kind of think of that as a queue in the sense of "stores the request".  As a practical matter, multiple interrupt lines from multiple devices tend to be simply "OR'd" together in the hardware to produce a single interrupt priority level, but there isn't any ordering so this sense it isn't a queue.   If the device doesn't hold the interrupt line high, an interrupt controller will typically have a latch, thus again "a queue".

Comment: ... details of how this works all depends on the interrupt architecture of your hardware.  You seem to be asking about Linux, so you are probably talking about Intel-style hardware.  IIRC, there's an interrupt controller device called "APIC"(?) built into the motherboards if not the CPUs themselves these days.  You should go read about how that works, and about how the processor handles interrupts in general.